# How do I create property of nested structure in ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, struct, viewmodel

I'm trying to create a ViewModel for the project in swift.
Below are the model and ViewModel code till now

Here is my struct model

```
struct Produce : Decodable {
    let products : [Item]
}

struct Item : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let place : origin
}

struct origin : Decodable {
    let location
}


class ProductViewModel {

     private let objProduce: Produce

    init(produce: Produce)
    {
        self.objProduce = produce
    }

  public var Name: String {
        //return objProduce.items[0].name
    }

}
```

I'm not how to create Name, Place property which is nested structure as shown above. this Name property - with objProduce.items[0].name is not correct way.

I want to create two property in ViewModel which is  Name and Place.

thanks

Comment: can you please elaborate that what your name property should return the value ?

Comment: This snippet doesn't even compile. You don't have a type specified for location in the origin struct. And if you really want to get the first name of the item in products you need to write: `return objProduce.products[0].name` and not `return objProduce.items[0].name`

Comment: products is array. What do you want to achieve ? .

Comment: "is not correct way", what do you mean by that? Isn't the way you want it to be or is causing an error? since you have used `objProdcue.items` instead of `objProduce.products` and does not compile at all!

Comment: @ prekshya basnet  - i don't want to return objProduce.products[0].name instead I want to have property for each name and place of struct Item.

Comment: @manishaupadhyay I think you want to bind name and place of viewModel to labels in a view. Since your model is an array of Items, why don't you add a function to get an Item and access name and place property. `getItem(at index: Int) -> Item'. This way you will get an Item object from where you can get your name and place property.